# How do I use an Ubuntu notebook as second monitor for a Fedora desktop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora

I was wondering if there is a possibility to use my netbook with 12.04 as a second monitor for my Fedora desktop, because its keyboard is broken but everything else is running just fine.

I already read about x2x, but I hope there is a more direct way to do this (I mean not over the WLAN but e.g. via LAN etc).

Would it be possible to directly use the monitor without even running the laptop? For example through an VGA adapter?

Comment: would be grateful if somebody could make a hint why it does not have anything to do with ubuntu? I guess connecting to an ubuntu laptop is not sufficient?